# What causes 503 Errors when loading tiles from CartoDB?

Tags: carto, error

I'm currently having great difficulty loading my visualizations onto my webapp from the CartoDB cdn. A majority of the tile requests are returning 503 errors with this response :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
 <title>503 backend read error</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <h1>Error 503 backend read error</h1>
  <p>backend read error</p>
  <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
  <p>XID: 2031602388</p>
  <hr>
  <p>Varnish cache server</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this perhaps due to bad data migration?

Comment: All of the bad requests appear to be for references to cached versions of custom svg markers I'm using. I'm also getting a number of 400 (Bad Request) Responses. A sample response below: `{"error":"style0:point-filecouldnotbefound:'/home/ubuntu/tile_assets/cartodb_user_8503a79f-974b-4ffa-adb9-9f5f06f03480_db/~09bcb324d4de44bedca8239fff3b7843/cache/3383d6cd-pentagon.svg'"}`

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Could you please write to support@cartodb.com telling what is your CartoDB username? Cheers

Comment: Still seeing this errors. Will email support. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems there was a tile caching problem which is already resolved.

The "file could not be found" error should not appear again.

I have not seen any problem related to your public visualizations through the CDN.

Please contact us through support with more details.